# Count(*) and As in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-streaming, hiveql

I am trying to reference count(*) , save it as total and reference it later but it is not working

for eg :

```
  select ((count(*) as total)-count(a)),
  (total - count(b)),
   (total - count(c))
     from table;
```

What's wrong?

I know it can be done by

```
     select (count(*) -count(a)),
       (count(*) - count(b)),
       (count(*) - count(c))
         from table;
```

But I want to use count(*) only once, store it as a variable and use that variable

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the column as an alias when the alias and other column are in the same level of SELECT.

Its not possible because the query attempts to use the alias before it was defined. 
If you look at the logical query processing order of the clauses you will find that the WHERE clause is evaluated logically prior to the SELECT. The only clause where you can refer to column aliases assigned in the SELECT is ORDER BY, since it’s the only clause that is evaluated after the SELECT clause. You can’t even refer to an alias within the same SELECT clause where it was defined.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. Work around would be like below:

```
`select total,total-cntA,total-cntB,total-cntC`
`from`
`(select count(*)total,count(A)cntA,count(b)cntB,count(c)cntC from table1)`
```